# Emulating a web browser to wrap the functionality of several similar web sites

Tags: c++, html-parsing, web-crawler, javascript, interpreter

I'm interested in emulating the functionality of a web browser in C++ so that I can create a wrapper for several web sites. Right now, the biggest issues with these sites are that they make heavy use of JavaScript that interacts with the HTML DOM. Thus, the simple solution of using curl to download the page, and something like [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net) to parse its contents is out.

Next, I considered using something like [v8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) with curl, and that solves the issue of interpreting the JavaScript on the page nicely. However, it doesn't solve the issue of connecting the HTML DOM methods with the JavaScript; in other words, `document.getElementById()` would fail in v8.

Next, I considered [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/), which seems like it's perfectly suited to emulate a web browser--after all, Chromium and Safari both utilize it in their web browsers. However, it's a little too complete. I don't need all of the rendering aspects it includes.

So, I'd be looking for some way to:

1. Make an SSL connection to a web site
2. Interpret the JavaScript on that web site in connection with the HTML DOM
3. Set the value of the username/passwords `<input>` fields with my username and password
4. Simulate clicking the "Submit" button by calling the `formSubmit()` function, from `<input type="button" onClick="formSubmit()">`
5. Handle the HTTP POST form action and the subsequent HTTP 301 and JavaScript redirects (accomplished using `window.location`)
6. Repeat 2-5 as needed

Besides what I've already considered, what other options do I have? Ideally, I'd want this to be extremely lightweight, without requiring linking to many libraries.

I'm primarily concerned with developing for Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: You want an extremely light-weight application that requires no external libraries and performs HTTP requests with SSL, executes JavaScript and emulates human interface activity? Well, +1 for being ambitious!

Comment: @Kerrek well, there are really lightweight solutions to many of the issues. HTTP requests with SSL isn't too difficult with libcurl and OpenSSL. Both of those libraries are very well-documented, and by no means a hack. Emulating human activity requires the inclusion/linkage of no other libraries, but rather making intelligent http requests (i.e., not bombarding the server with thousands per second). I know this is a very complex application, and I'm familiar with the intricacies. I'm just trying not to re-invent the wheel too much.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this sounds all too much like a brute-force program. Disregarding that, and since you don't seem to need to render any website, I think you should just fetch the file through cURL or something, then parse it, check for the form through using a regex, retrieve the form action, then make a request using the method taken from the `<form>` tag and whichever input you want.

Problem is, there would be no proper way to know when is it that you've logged in properly, unless you made some kind of per-site checking. This comes mainly from the fact that many sites use sessions rather than direct cookies or HTTP auth, and since you can't read from sessions directly, it is impossible for you to guess when the session has changed.

That's the most lightweight solution I can come up with right now.

Comment: -1 for suggesting regexes to parse a website! Maintaining cookies during a login process shouldn't be very hard with curl, either.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Regex would be much faster than parsing the entire DOM using whichever engine you want. I'm not talking about maintaining cookies, what I'm saying is that, since most websites work with sessions (and they set SESSID as soon as the user visits the site, regardless of their login status), he would have to parse the HTML accordingly to find out whether he is logged in or not.

Comment: @Julian It's not a brute force program, but thanks for speculating. This is quite legal; I'm developing a much lighter and much more efficient way to get the same functionality out of several web sites, without dealing with all of the graphic/layout nonsense. However, curl is a state machine, so it's able to keep track of the session data & cookies, so I don't see how that would be impossible...

Comment: The impossibility lies on detecting your own state (in reading the session data). The server will generate content depending on your session information, but you won't be able to read whatever is into your session (ehm, as an analogy, you can't access PHP's $_SESSION by yourself). Thus, your only option left is parsing HTML to check whether you have been logged in or not, and this would be a per-site parsing, since every site displays content in different manner.